# Regarding Nutch to crawl authenticated sites

Tags: nutch

we need to crawl data from a url which is authenticated with username and password. 
1) we have configured httpclient-auth.xml with the following credentials

```
<credentials username="xxxx" password="xxxxxx">
 <default/>
</credentials>
```

2) we have configured nutch-site.xml with the following properties

```
<property>
  <name>http.agent.name</name>
  <value>Nutch Crawl</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>http.auth.file</name>
  <value>httpclient-auth.xml</value>
  <description>Authentication configuration file for 'protocol-httpclient' plugin.</description>
</property>
```

While we try to fetch the data we got only one Url which is present in seed.txt file we didn't get any errors but still we are getting only one crawled data.

what we are missing here.